# Time difference between system time and user inpuit time in C Programming

Tags: c, time

I am trying to make a program which calculates the difference between system local time and a user input time.

I have had a crack at it but I am now stuck and unsure on what to do now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct TIME{
    int hour, minute, second;
}TIME;

int main(){
    TIME t1, t3;
    int seconds1, seconds2, totalSeconds;

    time_t current_time;
    char* c_time_string;

    current_time = time(NULL);
    c_time_string = ctime(&current_time);

    printf("Current time is %s", c_time_string);

    printf("Input desired time in HH:MM:SS (input as '12:12:12'): ");
    scanf("%d:%d:%d",&t1.hour, &t1.minute, &t1.second);

    seconds1 = t1.hour*60*60 + t1.minute*60 + t1.second;
    seconds2 = current_time.hour*60*60 + current_time.minute*60 + current_time.second;
    totalSeconds = seconds1-seconds2;

    t3.minute = totalSeconds/60;
    t3.hour = t3.minute/60;
    t3.minute = t3.minute%60;
    t3.second = totalSeconds%60;

    printf("Time difference is: %02d:%02d:%02d\n", t3.hour, t3.minute, t3.second);      
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is I am not sure on how to calculate the difference between my current time and my t1 (user input time) as I get errors saying they're not apart of the same structure or union.

Would be good if any of you could help me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_time` is of type `time_t` which is basically an integer and does not have member variable like `struct`s.

So you can't do like `current_time.hour`.

[`time_t`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/time.h/time_t) stores the total number seconds from the [UNIX epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

The user given time in your program does not include details like year, month, etc and has just hour, minute and second information. The `time_t` that you get via `time()` has the *total number* number of seconds from the UNIX epoch.

So, you may want to use just the hour, minute, second information like

```
time_t t=time(NULL);
struct tm *c=localtime(&t);
int seconds2 = c->tm_hour*60*60 + c->tm_min*60 + c->tm_sec;
```

[`struct tm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/time.h.html) is a structure to store components of the calendar time and `localtime()` localtime converts the calendar time into local time and returns a pointer to a `struct tm`.

`tm_hour`, `tm_min` and `tm_sec` are members of `struct tm` denoting th hour, minute and second respectively.

Note that the hour in `tm_hour` is in 24 hours format. If you want a 12 hour version, use `tm_hour%12`.

Answer (score 1):

`current_time` is of type `time_t` which is an integer that holds the number of seconds since UNIX epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC). It is not a struct that holds the time of day in members like `.hour`, `.minute` and `.second`.

To get the time of day you have to break down `current_time` into to a `struct tm` of the timezone of your choosing:

```
/* 
  break down current_time into calendar time representation using
  local timezone
 */
struct tm *lt = localtime(&current_time);

/* Calculate seconds since last midnight */
seconds2 = lt->tm_hour*60*60 + lt->tm_min*60 + lt->tm_sec;
```